# How to prove that the Hilbert Cube ($H^\infty$ ) is totally bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have the following definition:

**Definition**

> A set A in a metric space (M, d) is said to be **totally bounded** if, given any $\epsilon >0$, there exist finitely many points $x_1, ..., x_n \in M$ such that $A \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n} B_\epsilon(x_i)$.

**Defintion**:

> **The Hilbert cube $H^\infty$** is the collection of all real sequences $x = (x_n)$ with $|x_n|\leq 1$ for $ n = 1, 2, ...$

Furthermore the question refers to an exercise:

> A metric space is called **seperable** if it contains a countable dense subset.

**Question:** How do I prove that $H^\infty$ is totally bounded?

I don't have any clue how I should handle this, thanks in advance!

Comment: What metric on $H^\infty$ do you take?

Comment: Can you explain why your definition differs from the usual one of the [Hilbert cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube)? It's sort of important, since the traditional Hilbert cube is compact, of course.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

With your definition, $H^{\infty}$ is not totally bounded, as you can find an infinite subset $\{e_n\}$ such that $d(e_m, e_n) \ge 1$ for all $m\ne n$. ( for whatever reasonable norm you are considering).

Are you sure it's not " $|x_n|\le \frac{1}{n}$  " ?

Comment: The definition in my book says $|x_n| \leq 1$ unfortunately.. Could you give an example of such an infinite subset $\{e_n\}$?